# angular module name global declaration and reuse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web

Need help in generalizing angular module name,

```
angular.module('my-old-name-app', [])
```

I am using this in around 100+ controller files.
Now I want to change module name from **my-old-name-app** to **my-new-name-app**, so I have to do that change manually in all files.
Is there any way we can avoid this?
Can we have a common global declaration of module name and reuse it in all files??
I tried but couldn't find any suitable solution.
Note: As it's an existing project. I can't restructure/re-design.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using this in around 100+ controller files.

So don't use it in *all* your controllers. Anyway, you can avoid this problem if you design your application in more modular fashion. The recommended approach is to split application into multiple modules, by feature for example. Then the main module you want to rename would be used in only one place. The definition of the app then could be something like this:

```
angular.module('mu-old-name-app', [
    'app.dashboard',
    'app.profile',
    // ...
]);
```

Then module `app.dashboard` would included corresponding controllers, services, etc. Module `app.profile` would include its own stuff, etc.

Comment: As it's an existing project, It's hard not to use it in all files. I can't restructure entire project. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you want to do it right then you will have to have better structure. You can easily move parts of the app into submodules one by one. But until it's not the case you will have to use global find and replace in all the app. Also easy solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid global variables in angularjs applications, there is a very good and clean [style-guide made from J. Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Of course if you need to rework the whole app, you need to search and replace the old module-name in each file that uses it.

A good way to build angularjs application is using **more than 1 module**,
giving a blog example. A blog generally is composed by these components:

1. **dashboard** - for post editing
2. **list and single views**
3. **about** for author information
4. **contacts** for keeping in touch with the author

now, you have many ways to structure your app, the easy way is to have a single module called **blog** and attach to it every component, but, in case of future refactoring you will get frustrated.

A good solution, instead, is to split your app creating a module for each component:

```js
angular
  .module('blog.dashboard')
;
angular
  .module('blog.about')
;
angular
  .module('blog.contacts')
;


angular
  .module('blog', [
    'blog.dashboard',
    'blog.about',
    'blog.contacts'
  ])
;
```

Comment: just as an example, In case "blog.contacts" is used in more than 50+ file and you want to rename "blog.contacts" to "blog.RENAME.contacts", still we have to manually change it in all files. right?

Comment: First of all It's an existing project. I think that's not answer of my question.